# Identify Atmel processor

Tags: atmel

I'm wondering if anybody can tell me which processor this is:

[image: Atmel processor]

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Kinda looks like a ATmega8u2.

Here's [a link](http://www.microchip.com/wwwproducts/en/ATMEGA8U2) to a product page for it.